# copy combobox selected item to the gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Inside windows Form I have combobox which is populated with articles, I display only Name inside that combo box using this code

```
cmbArticleList.DataSource = GetAllArticles();
cmbArticleList.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

using onclick button I don't know how to copy entire object `Article` (it's properties(`Code`, `Price`, ...)) to the gridview or some other control inside same form window.

Comment: How is `article` defined?  That definition could make all the difference in your answer...

Comment: I dont know what do you mean how is defined, it's entity which has properties Id int, Name string, Price decimal, Code string, ...

Comment: Post the code where you declare it, please.

Comment: I've pasted here, http://pastebin.com/1riibiwb

Comment: When you say the whole object Article, does it mean all the rows in the Article table or simply the one being selected in the Combobox will be copied to a GridView for example?

Comment: I mean selected Article, not all the Article rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare a global variable in your Form for the Article like:

```
private List<Article> list;
```

So, before you bind your List to your `ComboBox` you put it on your globally defined list first and Add a `ValueMember` for your `ComboBox` particularly the `Primary Key` from your table to uniquely identify the value like:

```
list = GetAllArticles();
cmbArticleList.DataSource = list; 
cmbArticleList.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbArticleList.ValueMember = "Id";
```

So, when you click a `Button` you could then get the specific Article from your list and put it on a `DataGridView` for example like:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Article selectedArticle = list.Where(Articleid => Articleid.Id == int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
        row.Cells[0].Value = selectedArticle.Id;
        row.Cells[1].Value = selectedArticle.Id2;
        row.Cells[2].Value = selectedArticle.Group;
        row.Cells[3].Value = selectedArticle.Code;
        row.Cells[4].Value = selectedArticle.Name;
        row.Cells[5].Value = selectedArticle.Price;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Now, this assumes that you have a `DataGridView` with six (6) columns.

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows you how to display the article content in a richtextbox control.

1. Assign the article name or identifier to the display member property.
2. Assign the article content to the value member property.
3. Subscribe to the SelectedItemChanged event of the combobox.
4. When the SelectedItem changes then set the text property of the richtextbox to the SelectedValue property of the combobox as a string.

   ```
   public void controlInit() {
       DataTable articleInfo = new DataTable();
       articleInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
       articleInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Article"));
       DataRow dataRow1 = articleInfo.NewRow();
       DataRow dataRow2 = articleInfo.NewRow();
       dataRow1["Name"] = "Article 1";
       dataRow1["Article"] = "Article 1 content";
       dataRow2["Name"] = "Article 2";
       dataRow2["Article"] = "Article 2 content";
       articleInfo.Rows.Add(dataRow1);
       articleInfo.Rows.Add(dataRow2);
       this.comboBox1.DataSource = articleInfo;
       this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
       this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Article";
       this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged +=
           new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
   }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
       this.richTextBox1.Text = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
   }
   ```